# Extract from an array of objects ones that have propertie using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a big array of objects and i need to get the objects that have the propertie `def` set. No mather the value...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter an array of objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388371/filter-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @SergeK. That's not the same question.  I read this as they want the objects that have a certain property set, not just that property.

Comment: @Archer you're probably right, do you think I should remove my vote ?

Comment: @SergeK. Up to you.  I've marked it as a dupe as well so I think it still stands.  Between us we've probably found a duplicate :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if a property is present, and `Array.prototype.filter` to filter only those items.

```js
objArray = [ { def: 1, bar: 2}, { foo: 3, bar: 4}, { def: 5, bar: 6} ];

var result = objArray.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('def'));
console.log(result);
```

for es5 compatibility

```js
objArray = [{
  def: 1,
  bar: 2
}, {
  foo: 3,
  bar: 4
}, {
  def: 5,
  bar: 6
}];

var result = objArray.filter(function(item) {
  return item.hasOwnProperty('def')
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Archer Which function above has a problem with IE? Is it the fat arrow function you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

There is not such function in lodash although you can try following code

```
`let aFilteredArray = [];
    _.forEach(YourArray,function(oElement){
      if(!_.isEmpty(oElement.def)){
        aFilteredArray.push(oElement);
      }
    };
```